# How to have a background-color overshadow/transition ontop of background-image without a overlay mask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have a CSS element that has a background color:

```css
.item-content {
  width:  100%;
  height: 100%;

  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border:2px solid #021a40;
  background-color: white;

}
```

But on page load dynamically I add a background URL property (make the div here as well):

```
var image = document.createElement("div");
image.className = "item-content";
image.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imageSourceUrl + ")";
```

The div's background image is shown over top of the color. I can animate the opacity of the background image to fade away on hover:

```
$container.on('mouseenter', ".item-content", function (event) {
        var target = event.target;
        var $target = $(target);

        $(target).css('-webkit-transition', 'opacity 0.2s ease-in-out');
        $(target).css('transition', 'opacity 0.2s ease-in-out');
        $(target).css('opacity', '0');

    });

    $container.on('mouseleave', ".item-content", function (event) {
        var target = event.target;
        var $target = $(target);

        $(target).css('-webkit-transition', 'opacity 0.2s ease-in-out');
        $(target).css('transition', 'opacity 0.2s ease-in-out');
        $(target).css('opacity', '1');
    });
```

**Is there a way to animate the color to overshadow the image and animate it to full opacity (white) when hovered? Maybe something to do with z-index?**

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "overshadow" o.o

Comment: Is there a way for the background-color to be shown in front of the background image instead of vice versa?

Comment: only if you create something like mask above element with another div on position absolute or pseudo element :after or :before

Comment: I need to find a solution that involves only one div element, no mask.

Comment: but you can use pseudo element then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to animate the color to overshadow the image and
>   animate it to full opacity (white) when hovered?

If you do not need to support IE/Edge, then you could play with the [`background-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode) properties.

<sup>*Note: Tested only with Chrome, and FireFox.*</sup>

**Example Snippet:**

```js
var image = document.createElement("div");
image.className = "item-content";
image.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://lorempixel.com/200/200)";
document.getElementById('wrap').appendChild(image);
```

```css
.item-content {
  width:  200px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid #021a40; 
  background-size: 100% 100%; background-color: white;
  background-blend-mode: color-burn;
  transition: background-color .5s;
}
.item-content:hover { background-color: transparent; }
```

```html
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

**Example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/vh24a0wt/**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `z-index` for this purpose. `z-index` value is specified for stacking HTML elements.

In your case, I might suggest using `background-image: url(imagepath), linear-gradient(color, color)`. And here you can play with the order of `url` and `linear-gradient`.

Note that `color` might be hexadecimal, rgb, rgba, or hsl. 
Note also that this use of `background-image` is CSS3, take a look at W3Schools guide on this. [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp).